# relation "blog_blog" does not exist - error in Django app

Tags: python, django

I am to write simple Django blog application.

`Django Version: 2.0.4`
http://dpaste.com/0H62TQY - this is error output. ( I hope it's safe to show this file all over the Internet =) )

`models.py` look like

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.utils import timezone


class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='', editable=False, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "blog"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {'slug': self.slug}
        return reverse('blog_detail', kwargs=kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`views.py`look like

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView

from .models import Blog


class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/blog.html'
    queryset = Blog.objects.order_by('-created_at')


class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/blog-detail.html'
```

`urls.py` look like

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]*)/$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name='blog_detail'),
]
```

This is my `blog.html`

```
                    {% for blog in blog_list %}
                    <div class="item-blog-txt p-t-33">
                        <h4 class="p-b-11">
                            <a class="m-text24" href="{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}">
                                {{ blog.title }}
                            </a>
                        </h4>

                        <div class="s-text8 flex-w flex-m p-b-21">
                                <span>
                                    {{ blog.author }}
                                    <span class="m-l-3 m-r-6">|</span>
                                </span>
                        </div>

                        <p class="p-b-12">
                            {{ blog.body|linebreaksbr }}
                        </p>

                        <a class="s-text20" href="{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}">
                            Continue Reading
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-8"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

`blog-detail.html` look like `<a href="{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}">` and `{{ blog.title }}` and can say everything.
If you need something else to show, email me.
`makemigrations` and `migrate` was made.
Thank you very much.

Comment: If this is a new app you need to run `makemigrations blog`. `makemigrations` on its own will not do anything.

Comment: Can we see the migration files for the Blog model?

Comment: @Cole https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4ercdbvk8wvs2ea/AAAyh3W_udjRBakiA6SW2iRZa?dl=0

Comment: @solarissmoke it is not work

Comment: @asergey Migration files appear fine. From the error, your Database doesn’t have the table for your Blog model, could you share the output for ‘./manage.py migrate’?

Comment: @Cole https://pastebin.com/FSp5g9KZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the problem in database.
It was a new project so I could also just delete and start a new database.